# What's the way I can link or use classes from a java gradle project in a new java gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly, because in my new java project I include the following methods in settings.gradle file

```
include ":genericname"
project(":genericname").projectDir = file("../path_of_the_project")
```

And later I added to my build.gradle file the following

```
implementation project(":genericname")
```

Also I link the existing project with Gradle tab in IntelliJ to this new project. But still getting:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'GenericClass'

Whenever I want to import it to a new java class in the new project. Don't know if I get my point but the idea is simple use a gradle project into another new one.

This is where I'm basing my project
https://riptutorial.com/gradle/example/9627/depend-on-another-gradle-project

Comment: The structure looks correct. See Gradle docs for [multi module](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) project structure and [how to add dependencies on projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html). Make sure you specify the correct project name and use correct build.gradle file to define a dependency. Also double check the config is correct by building the application from the command line.

Comment: Btw it is not necessary to add the `genericname` into the IDE project explicitly - IDE will link it automatically provided that your Gradle configuration is correct.

Comment: If you are using Android, check this https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: I forgot to mention that these are two TestNGProjects the ones that I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

It turns that Gradle doesn't have the feature to use other than src/main/java folder to import classes, I was using src/test/java to store my classes because I'm using Selenium library to create test, but if they're in this location or path it will never be possible to use them with Gradle include or imports.